# Insert only modified value in history table using update trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to use a trigger so when I update one column on MyTable, I will insert old value of MyTable in historytable

```
CREATE TRIGGER historytrigger
   ON MyTable 
   BEFORE UPDATE
as
BEGIN  
if UPDATING(`Unit`) 
INSERT INTO `historytable`(`id_forecast`, `Unit`) VALUES (old.`ID`, old.`Unit`);
ELSEIF UPDATING(`Project_Country`) 
INSERT INTO `historytable`(`id_forecast`, `Project_Country`) VALUES (old.`ID`, old.`Project_Country`);
.
.
.
.
END
```

this has an syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is how I fixed this problem

```
begin 
IF OLD.`column`!= NEW.`column` THEN
INSERT INTO `historytable` (`id_forecast`, `Unit`) VALUES (old.`ID`, old.`column`);
ELSEIF OLD.`column1`!= NEW.`column1` THEN
INSERT INTO `historytable` (`id_forecast`, `Project_Country`) VALUES (old.`ID`, old.`column1`);
ELSEIF OLD.`column2`!= NEW.`column2` THEN
INSERT INTO `historytable` (`id_forecast`, `Project_Country`) VALUES (old.`ID`, old.`column2`);
ELSEIF OLD.`column3`!= NEW.`column3` THEN
INSERT INTO `edited_forecasts` (`id_forecast`, `Project_Country`) VALUES (old.`ID`, old.`column3`);
END IF
end
```